# Field Normalizing in redux form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-redux, redux-form

I am working on project where I am using `redux-form`. I want to normalize the redux-form field . I want to achieve capitalize word normalization means when user input something it will automatically capitalize every words i-e ( For Example ) . Here it working fine with example but I want to capital full word if user want to input . Let suppose user type `( I Love STACKOVERFLOW )`. Then I want to capitalize every word and also consider if someone type full word in capital .

Thanks

**Code**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about something like this?

```
const input = "i love STACKOVERFLOW"
const words = input.split(" ")
const capitalized = words.map(word => word.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + word.slice(1))
const result = capitalized.join(" ")
console.log(result)
```

or with usage of lodash https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#upperFirst

Answer (score 1):

The `Field` component from `redux-form` has a [normalize](https://redux-form.com/8.3.0/docs/api/field.md/#-code-normalize-value-previousvalue-allvalues-previousallvalues-name-gt-nextvalue-code-optional-) prop.

[This example](https://redux-form.com/8.3.0/examples/normalizing/) is straight from the documentation that sounds in line with what you want. Here's an abbreviated version:

```
// somewhere outside form or component
const upper = value => value && value.toUpperCase()

// somewhere in your form
<Field
  name="shout"
  component="input"
  type="text"
  placeholder="Shout something!"
  normalize={upper}
/>
```